# Matching content with nested tags

Tags: .net, regex

I'd like to use .NET Regex to match a bit of a really broken HTML, and I am not sure how to do it.

I know that Regex is a poor tool for this job, but I only need to extract some basic text from a huge file which has some really poorly HTML markup inside and my problem seems like a piece of cake for someone good at Regex.

So, putting aside it's HTML for a moment, let's say I have this:

```
<span class=comment>First block with <span class=nest>nested</span> text.</span>
<stuff>
<more-badly-formatted-tags>
<td - out of nowhere>
<span class=comment>Other block with <span class=nest>nested</span> text.</span>
```

I'd simply like to get all contents of `span` tags, along with any nested `span` tags. For the example above, that would simply be:

```
First block with <span class=nest>nested</span> text.
Other block with <span class=nest>nested</span> text.
```

That's everything I need, that's why I didn't want to get into HtmlAgilityPack at all.

**What I've tried so far**

1. Naive Regex: `@"<span class=comment>(<?comment>.*)</span>"`: this will greedily match everything between the first and last `span`.
2. Lazy Regex: `@"<span class=comment>(<?comment>.*?)</span>"`: this will match the first closing `span` and won't work with nested tags.
3. Balanced: `@(?<tag>\<span\b[^\>]*\>)(?<comment>.*)(?<-tag>\</span\>)"`: but obviously I don't get the syntax because this is not working.

Can anyone help me with this?

**[Update]**

Note that there might be newlines between these `<span>` tags. Or, if you will, the whole string can be a single huge line.

Comment: How about simply: `<span.*?>(.*)</span>` ? That should do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about simply:

```
<span.*?>(.*)</span>
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/bX3gU2

Matches:

```
1.  `First block with <span class=nest>nested</span> text.`

2.  `Other block with <span class=nest>nested</span> text.`
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work if there is a newline anywhere between these `span` tags. I should have been clearer with my examples, but (if I am not mistaken) this is the same as my attempt no.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you what you want:

```
<span.*?>(.*)</span>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qNVmbkli1vo--m6N)